# User input and generating additional problems in simple Android math app

Tags: android

I'm new to Android (as well as Java) programming so please be gentle! ;-)

I'm creating a math app where the user shall solve a simple math problem. I have been tearing my hair off, searching the web for a similar question to get some pointers.

I've managed to generate a random math problem but I have absolutely no idea as to how to take the user's answer input and tell if it's the right or wrong answer? Also, after the user submits the answer, by clicking the button `(R.id.btnok)`, I want to display another random math problem.

Any help, tips or pointers are appreciated!

```
public class MathActivity extends Activity {

private MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spela);

    //Media player with toggle button
    final ToggleButton togglesound = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglesound);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
    togglesound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (togglesound.isChecked()) {
                mp.start();
            } else {
                mp.pause();
            }   
        }
    });

    //Two random integers adding up to the sum of 10
    int min = 1;
    int max = 10;
    Random randomint = new Random();
    int randomint1 = randomint.nextInt(max - min +1) + min;
    int randomint2 = 10 - randomint1;
    //Displays random problem in textview
    TextView displayrandomproblem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvrandomproblem);
    displayrandomproblem.setText(randomint1 + " + " + randomint2 + " = ");

    //Fetches user answer and converts it to an integer
        EditText answer = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editanswer); {
        if (answer.getText().toString().length() > 0){
            int answerInt = Integer.parseInt(answer.getText().toString());
        }
        }
    //What to do if lenght of answer is in fact 0?
        //else{}
            //}
    //}
    //What to do with the string?
}
    //Releasing media player on pause
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mp !=null) {
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

So are you asking how to check if the user's answer is the correct one ? Im guessing you want to compare it with the result of the actual puzzle Which is `randomint1 + randomint2` and then show something on the screen saying if the answer is correct or not.

If you do get an empty string from the answer EditText, then show a Toast message and tell the user that the answer field is empty.